# How to get only the node inside another node in xml using DOM parser in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, selectnodes

I have to get the node values inside a node. But I end up in getting the values same node type from other nodes.

This is my xml structure (Sample)

```
    <Hello>
    <Morning>
    <hr>8</hr>
    <min>12</min>
    <sec>25</sec>
    <Food>
    <fooditem>
    <main>Burger</main>
    <drink>milk</drink>
    <fruit>banana</fruit>
    </fooditem>

    <fooditem>
    <main>Toast</main>
    <drink>butter milk</drink>
    <fruit>banana and apple</fruit>
    </fooditem>
    </Food>
    </Morning>
    <Evening>
 <hr>15</hr>
    <min>12</min>
    <sec>25</sec>
     <Food>
    <fooditem>
    <main>Burger</main>
    <drink>milk</drink>
    <fruit>banana</fruit>
    </fooditem>
 </Food>
    </Evening>
    <Evening>
<hr>15</hr>
    <min>12</min>
    <sec>25</sec>
     <Food>
    <fooditem>
    <main>Burger</main>
    <drink>milk</drink>
    <fruit>banana</fruit>
    </fooditem>
<fooditem>
    <main>Burger</main>
    <drink>milk</drink>
    <fruit>banana</fruit>
    </fooditem>
 </Food>
    </Evening>
    <Evening>
<hr>15</hr>
    <min>12</min>
    <sec>25</sec>
     <Food>
    <fooditem>
    <main>Burger</main>
    <drink>milk</drink>
    <fruit>banana</fruit>
    </fooditem>
 </Food>
    </Evening>

    </Hello>
```

Now the problem is I can able to get the values from the XML. But what my code does is it gets all the food item values from all other nodes. I have to get the morning food values and then evening and then evening one by one in order.

My code

```
File fXmlFile = new File("c://food.xml");
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

     System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

     NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("fooditem");


     System.out.println("----------------------------");

     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

         Node nNode = nList .item(temp);


     if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

             Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
             System.out.println("main: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("main").item(0).getTextContent());
             System.out.println("drink: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("drink").item(0).getTextContent());
             System.out.println("fruit: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("fruit").item(0).getTextContent());
         }
     }
```

output: current :

```
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana    Toast    
    butter milk    
    banana and apple    
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana    
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana    
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana 


    Burger    
    milk    
    banana    Toast    
    butter milk    
    banana and apple    
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana    
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana    
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana  



    Burger    
    milk    
    banana    Toast    
    butter milk    
    banana and apple    
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana    
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana    
    Burger    
    milk    
    banana
```

Expected OUtput:

```
    Burger    
milk    
banana    
Toast    
butter
milk    
banana and apple    
Burger    
milk    
banana    
Burger    
milk    
banana    
Burger    
milk    
banana
```

The expected output is when it gets the childnodes itshould get the fooditem childnode belonging to only Morning tag and the it should get from the evening tag. In current for each evening and morning it gets all the values from food item and again it gets all the values

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want.  Can you please edit your question to show your current output and your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     System.out.println("----------------------------");
     NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("fooditem");

     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

         Node nNode = nList .item(temp);


     if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

             Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

             NodeList children = eElement.getChildNodes();

             for(int i=0;i<children.getLength();i++){
                 Node item = children.item(i);

                 System.out.println(item.getTextContent());


             }


         }
     }
```